# How to resolve Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 AaptException?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4. But when I am creating new project and building it I am getting the following error. How to resolve below issue :

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

Issues:
 - ERROR:  failed to create directory D:\Android Code\SampleApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\mkumar2\sampleapp
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.AaptV2Jni.buildException(AaptV2Jni.java:136)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.AaptV2Jni.makeValidatedPackage(AaptV2Jni.java:80)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:40)

Comment: have you tried with invalidate cache and restart option?

Comment: @BabulPatel Yes I tried but still getting same issue.

Comment: https://twitter.com/androidstudio/status/875311569219006464

Comment: post your gradle wrapper properties file here

Comment: @EugenPechanec  after disabling AAPT2 in gradle.propertіes fіle using: 
android.enableAapt2=false  I am ableto build and run app. Thanks

Comment: Solution to this problem in the link below ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44776951/1804131