# Build error with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-instant-apps

I am currently in the process of developing an Instant app, for which I have restructured my monolithic app into feature modules. 
Everything was up and running till Android Studio canary 3, but after an update to **Android Studio Canary 4** my project fails to build with the following error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':minimoBase:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebugAndroidTest'.

> Directory '/Users/nayak.vishal/projectData/minimo_instant_app_project/putica-client-android-
native/minimoBase/build/intermediates/data-binding-info/androidTest/debug' 
specified for property 'xmlOutFolder' does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you changed version in  "build.gradle(applicationName)"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following procedure worked as a workaround for this issue:

Execute the following build commands on the gradle command line

1) gradlew clean

2) gradlew :appModule:assembleDebug

> - here appModule is the name of the app module for building the installable apk
> - the build is successful and the debug apk generated in the output folder can be installed successfully

3) gradlew :instantAppModule:assembleDebug

> - here instantAppModule is the name of the instant app module
> - the build is successful and the instant app apks can be installed and launched via deep link

Once the above command line builds are successful, building via Android Studio Canary 4 also stops throwing the build error.

Comment: These links should help :) https://docs.gradle.org/0.9-rc-2/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 6):

I got similar error when I turn on `data-binding` for library module. When I turn it off and move all classes that require `data-binding` to `app` module, it works. So I guess there is a problem that DataBinding doesn't work on Library module any more ( Gradle 2.x fine with this).

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = false 
}
```

I am using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5` and Android Studio 3.0 Preview Canary5

## UPDATE

Although the original answer worked, I really want to turn on `data-binding` on my library module, where I implement some base classes using binding technique. I move them back to `library` module and upgrade `kotlin` version to the latest one `1.1.3-2`. Suddenly it works also. I am not sure which one is the better but both ways work for me.

## UPDATE 2

I am using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9` and kotlin `1.1.3-2` at this time and suddenly the problem re-appear.
Now I think the problem doesn't come from Kotlin. My library module turned  `dataBiding { enabled=true}`, but it doesn't have any layout file. I tried to create a fake layout file wrapped by `<layout>` tag and it works

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue in AS 3.0 Canary-6. You solution resolved my issue. Thanks for the update. Actually by default data binding was true in the project.

Answer (score 3):

In your gradle.properties file , add the following line

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Recent versions of AS3.0 switched to using AAPT2 by default.
You can disable AAPT2 in your gradle.propertіes fіle with above mentioned line of code, and continue developing on AS3 canary 4.

Comment: this change doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue for me when I had a "base" feature module without any layouts (all my actual layouts are in separate features)

Adding a dummy layout XML file in the base feature (e.g. as `base/src/res/layout/dummy.xml`) meant the missing directory was created and the app compiled.

(this is using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6`)

Comment: This was the exact problem that I had. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @pete-harris is right. You should add at least one layout using as root element "layout" - the data binding root element for views. So, if you have none databinding layout configured, try to create one, like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <data></data>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout></layout>`

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, seems like a bug in Canary 4.

For now, as a workaround, I downgraded to Android Studio 3.0.0 Canary 3 ([This is an archive of all Android Studio releases](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html)) and also downgraded the Android Gradle plugin to `3.0.0-alpha3`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

Just check the Canary version after update. For that see Android Studio version just above the toolbar (File..Edit..View..line) where name at end like "Canary X".-> X is number like 3,4,5,etc.

**For example** suppose updated version(X) is 5.
Try to change that classpath in **build.gradle(applicationName)** to 3.0.0-alpha5 and sync(/Try) again:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
}
```

Means that updated version(X):-

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alphaX'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the gradle plugin version is already gradle:3.0.0-alpha4 and the distributionURL in gradle wrapper properties is set to gradle-4.0-rc-1-all.zip. This is auto prompted by Android Studio on update to Canay 4. So I don't think this is the reason for the build error.

Comment: incorrectly. I still got same error when changing the gradle version